# Split column into multiple columns

Tags: r, split

I have data in a csv file in a single column with 6954 values. I want to split this column into multiple columns such that each column has 122 data and next column has the next 122 data and so on. I guess, I will have a final matrix of 122 rows and 57 columns. Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Use `read.csv` to read in comma-seperated value files: https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/utils/html/read.table.html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Or this will do the trick as well:

```
x = 1:6954
dim(x) <- c(122, 57)
```

Answer (score 3):

Like this ?

```
x <- rep(1:122, 5)
xx <- matrix(x, nrow=122)
xx[1:5, ]
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    1    1    1    1    1
[2,]    2    2    2    2    2
[3,]    3    3    3    3    3
[4,]    4    4    4    4    4
[5,]    5    5    5    5    5
```

Answer (score 1):

A column can be split using the `colsplit` function which is part of the `reshape` package
[http://r.ramganalytics.com/r/split-a-column-by-a-character-using-colsplit-function/](http://web.archive.org/web/20140707185945/http://r.ramganalytics.com/r/split-a-column-by-a-character-using-colsplit-function/)